# Specified cast is not valid when invoking javascript function in webbrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, invokescript

I'm trying to invoke javascript function in webbrowser.
Website have separate file with javascript functions.
This is a part of website html file:

```
<div class="header">
    <a class="buttonrg" onclick="$(this).hide();remove('56442741')"> Remove </a>
</div>
```

This is remove function from .js file:

```
function remove(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/remove.php",
        data: "remove=" + id
    });
}
```

And I'm trying to call 'remove' function with this script in c#:

```
    public void RemoveOffer(int _id)
    {
        try
        {
            webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("remove", new object[] { _id.ToString() });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
     }
```

but always when I'm trying to call this script console is showing me an error: specified cast is not valid.

What could went wrong?

Comment: Check after changing `data: "remove=" + remove` to `data: { "remove": id }`

Comment: Is it only the C# code that is giving the error? Clicking the Remove on the page works fine?

Comment: @XtremeBytes yeah, code on page is working

Answer (score 0):

Change `data: "remove=" + remove` to `data: { "remove": id }`

Comment: Yeah, script on website is working, but when I'm trying to invoke this in webbrowser form it's still showing me the same message, so problem is in c# script.

Comment: Why don't you remove the ToString() call? It's an object array so the int would work as well.

Comment: I was trying to call it with String array before, that's why there is ToString(). Just forgot to remove it, but it's not working w/o this as well.

Comment: yeah.. still the same

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the `InvokeScript()` from a thread other than the one that created it? Doing this caused this exception to be thrown for me.

It's a strange error message given the circumstances, however I resolved this with an `Invoke()`

e.g.

```
    private void RemoveOffer(int _id)
    {
        if (webBrowser.InvokeRequired)
        {
            webBrowser.Invoke(new Action(() => { RemoveOffer(_id); }));
            return;
        }
        webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("remove", new object[] { _id }); // Not sure if the .ToString() is required...
    }
```